# How to avoid \n and \r in PHP using nl2br

Tags: php, space, nl2br

I am trying to avoid the \n and \r values from the mysql table  using nl2br as shown below

```
$profileDetails['address']=nl2br($profileDetails['address']);
```

But it is not working.

the value in `$profileDetails['address']` is `"Naduvilachirayil House,\r\nAnaprampal North P.O,\r\nThalavady"`.

But when I check,

```
echo nl2br("Naduvilachirayil House,\r\nAnaprampal North P.O,\r\nThalavady");
```

It is working..

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is that `$profileDetails['address']` doesn't have the value you think it does.

Comment: `var_dump(nl2br($profileDetails['address']))` Please

Answer (score 2):

`nl2br` does not convert the string `\n` into a `<br>`. It converts new lines into a `<br>`.  To show the difference:

```
"\n" === "
";

$profileDetails['address'] === "Naduvilachirayil House,\\r\\nAnaprampal North P.O,\\r\\nThalavady";
```

That is to say, the value from your database is a literal `\` character followed by an `n` character. `\n` only means "new line" when the string is being defined.

Comment: The reason why those two strings aren't equivalent is because you're probably on a machine that doesn't encode line endings in `\n`. [Here's a demo](http://codepad.org/wVAboh0V) for Windows `\r\n` that works fine.

Comment: How to solve this problem.. plz help me. I would like to get the out in seperate lines

Comment: @user1055453 The problem is with the code that inserts the values into the database, not with the code that retrieves them. `\r\n` should not appear in your database.

Comment: how can I avoid \r and \n to insert in to data base.